# Why the user isn't properly authenticated?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I've got a problem with Spring Security. Here is my code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    private final UserDetailServiceImpl userDetailService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtFilter jwtFilter;

    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailServiceImpl userDetailService) {
        this.userDetailService = userDetailService;
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Two ways of disabling csrf in spring security 7.0
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        http.csrf((crsf)->crsf.disable());
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> {
                            auth.requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                                    .anyRequest().authenticated();


                        }
                )
                .userDetailsService(userDetailService)
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .sessionManagement( (sessionManagement) -> sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .exceptionHandling((exceptionHandling)->{
                    exceptionHandling.authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
                        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, authException.getMessage());
                    } );
                })
                .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);


        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();

    }

}
```

```
@Service
public class JwtUtil {
//    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String SECRET_KEY="secret";
    private int JWT_EXPITE = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60; //30 days

    public String extractUsername(String token) {

        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }
    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET_KEY).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }

    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        return createToken(claims, userDetails.getUsername());
    }

    private String createToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {

        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + JWT_EXPITE))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, SECRET_KEY).compact();
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = extractUsername(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // 1. get the authentication header. Tokens are supposed to be passed in the authentication header
        final String header = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        // 2. validate the header and check the prefix
        if(!StringUtils.hasText(header) || (StringUtils.hasText(header) && !header.startsWith("Bearer "))){
            chain.doFilter(request, response);          // If not valid, go to the next filter.
            return;
        }

        // If there is no token provided and hence the user won't be authenticated.
        // It's Ok. Maybe the user accessing a public path or asking for a token.

        // All secured paths that needs a token are already defined and secured in config class.
        // And If user tried to access without access token, then he won't be authenticated and an exception will be thrown.

        // 3. Get the token
        String token = header.split(" ")[1].trim();

        try {   // exceptions might be thrown in creating the claims if for example the token is expired
            // 4. Get user identity and set it on the spring security context
            String username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(token);
            UserDetails userDetails = userRepository.findByUsername(username).orElse(null);


            // 5. Validate the token
            if(!jwtUtil.validateToken(token, userDetails)){
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
                return;
            }

                // 5. Create auth object
                // UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken: A built-in object, used by spring to represent the current authenticated / being authenticated user.
                // It needs a list of authorities, which has type of GrantedAuthority interface, where SimpleGrantedAuthority is an implementation of that interface
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails == null ? List.of() : userDetails.getAuthorities());
                auth.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                // 6. Authenticate the user
                // Now, user is authenticated
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            // In case of failure. Make sure it's clear; so guarantee user won't be authenticated
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        }finally {
            // go to the next filter in the filter chain
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }



    }
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String password;
    private String username;
    private LocalDate cohortStartDate;
    private Role role;


    public User(String password, String username, LocalDate cohortStartDate, Role role) {
        this.password = password;
        this.username = username;
        this.cohortStartDate = cohortStartDate;
        this.role = role;

    }

    public User(String password, String username, Role role) {
        this.password = password;
        this.username = username;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public User(User user) {
        this.username = user.getUsername();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.role = user.getRole();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List <GrantedAuthority> authority = new ArrayList<>();
        authority.add(new Role("ROLE_STUDENT" ));
        System.out.println(authority);
        return authority;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name="assignment")
@NoArgsConstructor

public class Assignment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String status;
    private String githubUrl;
    private String branch;
    private String codeRewievVideoUrl;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    private User user;
    public Assignment(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Assignment(String status, String githubUrl, String branch, String codeRewievVideoUrl, User user) {
        this.status = status;
        this.githubUrl = githubUrl;
        this.branch = branch;
        this.codeRewievVideoUrl = codeRewievVideoUrl;
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Here is my Service class

```
@Service
public class AssignmentService {

    @Autowired
    private AssignmentRepository assignmentRepository;
    public Assignment save(User user){
        Assignment assignment = new Assignment();
        assignment.setStatus("Needs to be submitted");
        assignment.setUser(user);
        return assignmentRepository.save(assignment);
    }
}
```

This is class for storing just username and password from request

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class AuthCredentialRequest {
    private String username;
    private String password;
}
```

and finally here is my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/assignments")
public class AssignmentController {

    @Autowired
    private AssignmentService assignmentService;

    @PostMapping("")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAssignment(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user){
        Assignment assignment = assignmentService.save(user);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(assignment);
    }


}
```

When I try to send a post request with following code I get 401 error

```
axios.post("api/assignments",{}, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${jwt}`
            }
        }).then((res)=>{
            if(res.status === 200) return res.json();
        }).then((data)=>{
            console.log(data)
        }).catch((err)=>console.log(err))
```

Here are logs i get in my console:

```
2023-07-30T11:21:25.502+02:00 DEBUG 11180 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /api/assignments
2023-07-30T11:21:25.502+02:00 TRACE 11180 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/13)
2023-07-30T11:21:25.503+02:00 TRACE 11180 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/13)
2023-07-30T11:21:25.505+02:00 TRACE 11180 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/13)
2023-07-30T11:21:25.506+02:00 TRACE 11180 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/13)
2023-07-30T11:21:25.507+02:00 TRACE 11180 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (5/13)
2023-07-30T11:21:25.508+02:00 TRACE 11180 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2023-07-30T11:21:25.508+02:00 TRACE 11180 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking JwtFilter (6/13)
2023-07-30T11:21:25.508+02:00 TRACE 11180 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (7/13)
2023-07-30T11:21:25.508+02:00 TRACE 11180 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/login', POST]
2023-07-30T11:21:25.508+02:00 TRACE 11180 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (8/13)
2023-07-30T11:21:25.508+02:00 TRACE 11180 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (9/13)
2023-07-30T11:21:25.509+02:00 TRACE 11180 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (10/13)
2023-07-30T11:21:25.510+02:00 TRACE 11180 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SessionManagementFilter (11/13)
2023-07-30T11:21:25.510+02:00 TRACE 11180 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-07-30T11:21:25.511+02:00 TRACE 11180 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2023-07-30T11:21:25.511+02:00 TRACE 11180 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (12/13)
2023-07-30T11:21:25.511+02:00 TRACE 11180 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (13/13)
2023-07-30T11:21:25.512+02:00 TRACE 11180 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@2db46778]
2023-07-30T11:21:25.519+02:00 TRACE 11180 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@2db46778] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@6e83eeb7
2023-07-30T11:21:25.519+02:00 TRACE 11180 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at com.lenroc.SubmissionApp.auth.JwtFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtFilter.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

I think it might be a problem with @AuthenticationPrincipal annotation in the endpoint parameter, but I have no idea where to start.

I have checked the request header and it sends the token correctly with the "Bearer " prefix. I have also changed mapping to just simple void function, printing out some text, but the result is the same: 401 error.

Comment: dont user JWTs as sessions as it is insecure. There is no jwt filter implementation in spring security because it is very insecure to use jwts as session holders. This entire implementation is bad practice and should not exist. If you need sessions use cookies, if you specifically need jwt you should implementOAuth2 using for instance Open ID connect using the built in tools that come with spring security. Whatever blogpost you have been following should be deleted.

Comment: spring security is a framework with excellent documentation that has a lot of pre built login implementations and you have completely ignored those to write some sort of strange custom security. Whats the point of having a security framework if you do not intend to use its features?